# Non-symmetric simple random walk stopping time

Tags: probability, markov-chains, martingales, random-walk

Say there is a random walk $\{S_n\}$ with $S_0=0$ and $0<p=P(S_1=1)<\frac{1}{2}$. We know such a random walk would go to $-\infty$ eventually. Define the stopping time $T=\inf\{n: S_n=-\infty\}$, how can we argue that the stopping time is finite a.s., i.e., $P(T<\infty)=1$?

I know we definitely will use $0<p=P(S_1=1)<\frac{1}{2}$, and I know for such $p$, the returning time is not finite, which is transient. How can I apply this to show the stopping time $T$ is finite a.s.? Or is there another approach to this?

Comment: Clearly for any $ n \geq 1 $, we must have $ S_n \geq - n > -\infty  $. Therefore, $ T \geq n $. Thus, $ T = \infty $. Thus, you can never have $ P (T < \infty ) = 1 $ for the $ T $ that you have defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not told us enough to reach your conclusions.

If you are saying each independent step is $+1$ with probability $p$ and $-1$ with probability $1-p$, with $p \lt \frac12$, then $S_n \not = -\infty$ for finite $n$, since $-n \le S_n \le n$.  So $\Pr(T \lt \infty)=0$.

Since $p \lt \frac12$ you could conclude that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} S_n = -\infty$$ with probability $1$ but that is not the same thing at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right about all the assumptions that I don't mention in my question (each independent step is +1 with probability p and −1 with probability 1−p, with p<1/2) From your argument, I think maybe we cannot reach the conclusion that the stopping time is finite a.s. The reason I asked this I want to check the conditions of Optional stopping theorem, so I can use it to reach another conclusion.

Comment: Hi.I am supposed to solve this problem:let $(S_{1},S_{2},S_{3},...)$ be a symmetric simple random walk (with the step $X_{n}$ taking on only the values $1$ and $-1$ with equal probabilities). Let $\alpha=\min (n:S_{n}=5)$  and $\beta=\min (n:S_{n}<-3)$ and the question is if $$min(\alpha,\beta)+1$$  $$max(\alpha,\beta)-1$$ are stopping times of the sequence $X=(X_{1},X_{2},...)$. I am trying to solve it but with no success.I would appreciate if you would be so kind to help me. Thanks  in advice.

Comment: @Laura Your question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917330/stopping-time-of-random-walk and you can answer it using [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time) *"Intuitively, this condition means that the decision of whether to stop at time $n$ must be based only on the information present at time $n$, not on any future information."*

Comment: yeah, but nobody replied the question, so I tried to find succesfull users of a similar topic. This is so abstract...

Answer (score 0):

Considering $\:\:S_n=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j,\:\:X_j\:\text{ i.i.d},\:X_j\in\mathbb Z.$

If $\:\:\mathbb E[X_j]<0,\:$ by the *strong law* of large numbers : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}\overset{a.s}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb E[X_j]<0\\\implies S_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}-\infty.$$

Thus, $$\inf\{n: S_n=-\infty\}<\infty,$$

So that the random walk will eventually reach its stopping time.